# Running Docker locally in browser on Windows10: Error - IP Not Found

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-machine

Ok, so here's my background first. I'm a noob in the world of commandline interfaces, but have been building websites off and on for a long time (10 yrs) using GUI's. So, I'm trying to make the switch to CLI's while also learning Docker.

Right now I'm stuck at trying to get Docker to load anything into my browser window. Here's what I've done successfully:

- Installed Docker CE on my Windows 10 Machine
- Setup a new virtual switch in Hyper-V Manager per [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#example) and restarted the computer.
- Created a new machine using this line of code `docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" manager1`

Now here's where things get a little interesting. When I run the above function (I've done it twice now) it stalls on the line: `Waiting for host to start...`

I waited for five minutes to see if it would do anything, before killing the operation. (oh, did I mention I'm running PowerShell in Adminstrator Mode - right click on the icon to "run as administrator").

So when I re-open PowerShell to check if the new "manager1" machine has been created it comes back affirmative, but with this:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
manager1   *        hyperv   Running                 Unknown   IP not found
```

As far as I can tell these are the steps that I need to take to get Docker to run locally in my browser window, but for the life of me, I'm lost!

Oh, I did downgrade my docker-machine version per a suggestion that I read in a git forum comment, but that was to remedy an issue with the `docker-machine create` command. Part of me wonders if I'm doing too much. But I honestly don't know what to do next.

[image: HyperV Manager Screenshot]

[image: Virtual Switch Manager Screenshot]

[image: PowerShell Docker Network and Docker Machine Screenshot]

---

**UPDATE:**

I don't know that this is progress, but in the Virtual Switch Manager, I did switch the external network device from the "Ethernet Connection" to the "Dual Band Wireless" option. Then I restarted my machine.  Now I'm showing that the state of the machine is "Timeout". I've also started and stopped my "docker-machine manager1". It sites on the `(manager1) Waiting for host to start...` line for about half a minute, then proceed to the `Waiting for SSH to be available...` where it just sits. Here's another screen shot that captures this:

[image: Powershell and Virtual Switch Manager screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my confusion was a result of looking beyond the documentation and getting a little confused. I still don't have this fully figured out but everything I was attempting to accomplish is detailed in this [getting started with Windows 10 pro article](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/docker-for-windows/#explore-the-application-and-run-examples).